# How to navigate to a new url without opening a new window in selenium (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to go to a new page using

`driver.get("url")`

but this opens a new window I want to open it in the same window; I couldn't find any solution for this

Comment: Do you have your browser preferences set to open links in a new tab?

Comment: @JohnGordon how do I look up it?